# How to create a session out of every time a user uses my webapp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To expand on my question, I have a playlist app that adds tracks to the Track table like so whenever the create action is invoked. However every time I open up an instance of localhost:3000, I see the same set of elements that have been added to the table.

What I want is for every time a user opens up my webapp to have his own session, to fragmenting off some of the table for a single user's playlist.

How do I go about doing this? The following shows how I add elements to the database in my program. If there is any more information required, let me know.

```
def create

    if is_url(params[:track][:query])   
        @trackinfo = getTrackInfo(params[:track][:query])
    else
        @trackinfo = youTubeQuery(params[:track][:query])

    end
    @track = Track.new(@trackinfo)
    @tracks = Track.all
    @video_ids = Track.pluck(:video_id) 

    if @track.save

    else 
        render :action=>"index"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully get your question but I'll give it a try.

You need to implement user sign in/sign out. In this way each user will have his own list of tracks. 
Use the devise gem. It is well tested and gives you all you need.

You can read more about Rails session here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Hope this help.

UPDATE

Each user that comes to your website gets a unique session thus you can use the session_id in place of the user_id.

Super simple solution:

Step 1: add a column to the tracks table called user_id (do not forget to add an index as well), session_id is a string.

Step 2: create a before_filter in your application_controller that sets the user variable:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter:set_user

  # ...

  def set_user 
    @user_id = cookies['_session_id'] # @user_id is a string
  end

  # ....

end
```

Step 3: in your create method do something like this

```
   # ...
   # Note this code is just to give you an idea 
   @new_track = Track.new(query: @trackinfo)
   @new_track.user_id = @user_id 
   @tracks = Track.where(user_id: @user_id)

   # ....
```

NOTE: A more flexible solution requires a users table and setting the current_user variable based on the user_id stored into the session. See the link above.

Hope this help.

Comment: So suppose I were making a website like this: http://youtubelister.com/, however the code I've written right now supports a single user. Without making the user authenticate, I want the multiple users to each have their own sessions of the site. Does that make sense? I'll go through your link, thanks for your input.

Comment: Louis93 I have updated my response. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful. One thing though, cookies['_session_id'] is returning nil everytime so I use the similar `request.session_options[:id]` instead. Is this an issue?

Answer (score 0):

create a definition to destroy, IF you maintain LOGIN LOGOUT sessions before going to logout just make call to Def Destroy using AJAX OR if u dont maintain logout sessions u can make use of event handlers Jquery beforeunload or java script onunload

```
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ ajax call to destroy track.all);
        or         $(window).unload(function(){ ajax call });
```

Comment: What if two users are using the site concurrently? Then your solution would not work yes?

Comment: Ummm yeah, but i can suggest Create a user for every session if the user adds any tracks and on exit destroy the user and tracks using session ID.